# Can't use get_field()

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a working AJAX function that sends a variable to a page I made within the template directory. I am using Advanced Custom Fields and execute the `get_field($name, $id)` function, but I get a 500 server error. I looked in my error log (Apache) and saw that it got an undefined function error. That's strange, because when I use it on front-page.php it actually works.

```
[Fri May 09 11:56:19.336469 2014] [:error] [pid 2235] [client 192.168.1.111:54118]
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field()
in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/Custom Theme/setphoto.php on line 4,
referer: 192.168.1.115/
```

PHP

```
<?php
$p = $_GET['p'];
$url = get_field("nieuwsveld", $p);
echo $url;
?>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".a_item").mouseover(function(){
            // Krijg url + id van href
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            var p = href.replace("http://192.168.1.115/?p=", "");
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "wp-content/themes/HSV Saints/setphoto.php?p="+p, true);
            xhr.send();

            xhr.onload = function(){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
           // $("#photo_news_photo").attr("src", img_url);


        });
    </script>
```

How can I enable WordPress to use get_field in an external file within my template directory?

Comment: Can you show your code.

Comment: I have addes my JavaScript code, but that's not the problem. The problem is that Advanced Custom Fields somehow is not enabled on that page or something, it does not recognise the function...

Comment: Any idea? I'm like stuck on this

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and fixed it by including acf.php at the top of the php file that handled the ajax request.

So for your code it would be

```
<?php

include_once(__DIR__.'path/to/file/acf.php');

$p = $_GET['p'];
$url = get_field("nieuwsveld", $p);
echo $url;

?>
```